# Add OneLogin into a WPF app, so that admin can control who is allowed to sigin in

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, onelogin

We have a WPF application developed in C#. We want to add OneLogin at the sign in screen.  So that only invited user can sign in the app, and admin can control/see who can login to the app.  I checked OneLogin website, but seem they only have samples for embedding the OneLogin authentication page into Web applications.  https://developers.onelogin.com/

I am not sure if we can use OneLogin as the authentication for a custom WPF application.

Comment: from [onelogin] tag wiki: Non-programming questions (e.g. general support) are OFF-TOPIC for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should implement either SAML or OpenID connect inside a web view as the authorization mechanism for your application.

This is the typical pattern used by native applications (either on the phone or desktop) and has the benefit of your application becoming just another service that OneLogin administrators can control SSO into.

I'll add that OpenID connect is probably a better choice as it doesn't require a back-end web service and could function as a single page Javascript app.